# How can I arrange my functions in order to use this class I made?

Tags: python, function, class

I am trying to use a weather GUI using Tkinter and I am following a tutorial @ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D8-snVfekto&t=3227s and I am trying to add my own class instead of using more code.

I keep getting errors stating that `weather is not defined` which I get, but how could I arrange my functions and classes to be able to use my class and print `return str(name) +' ' + str(description) +' '+ str(tempOverall)`?

I have tried to rearrange the code to run the `get_weather()` function but then I have to run and call the city name which I don't know yet until the user inputs the city name.

This is my class...

```
class temperature():
    def __init__(self):                                                                 
        super(temperature, self).__init__()
        self.tempOverall = (weather['main']['temp'])
        self.tempMin = (weather['main']['temp_min'])
        self.tempMax = (weather['main']['temp_min'])
temp = temperature()
```

and this is my where I create my Response...

```
def formatResponse(weather):
    name = (weather ["name"])
    description = (weather['weather'][0]['description'])

    return str(name) +' ' + str(description) +' '+ str(tempOverall)
```

Lastly this is where I use an API...

```
def get_weather(city):
    wether_key = "22c2d09d0eb26074b8c8b4a293f72682"
    url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather"
    params= {'APPID': wether_key, 'q': city, 'units': 'imperial'}
    response = requests.get(url, params=params)
    weather = response.json()

    label['text'] = formatResponse(weather)
```

Comment: Where (on what line) are getting you getting the error?

Comment: line 21 in temp = weather is not defined

Comment: The closest thing in the code in your question is `temp = temperature()`, so it's unclear what's wrong without including the code that causing the error in it. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

In your class temperature's init function, your code "self.tempOverall = (weather['main']['temp'])" use weather before define. You can pass the variable weather as the parameter of init function.

Answer (score 0):

While creating an object for temperature class pass weather as an argument and add weather as an argument in init method.

Comment: can you show what that would look like? so like this: def __init__(self, weather): and then call it like this temp = temperature(weather) btw i have a lambda "button = Button(frame, text="Get Weather", font=40, command=lambda: get_weather(entry.get()))"